# Images in one slide is being half in other slid

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[slide 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR7TO.png)
[slide2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6duV.png)

I dont know how to explain this ..but image from one slide is being displayed in the next slide too. Pls help... I have to clone The oikos minter page any help would be appreciated.

**here is the code for index.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {Container,SliderContainer,ButtonP, ButtonN,IMG } from './slider';
import './slider.css';

import img1 from '../../images/slider1.png';
import img2 from '../../images/slider2.png';
import img3 from '../../images/slider3.png';
import img4 from '../../images/slider4.png';
import img5 from '../../images/slider5.png';


function Slider() {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const slideRef = useRef(null);
  
  const TOTAL_SLIDES = 4;
  const images = [
    {
      src : img1,
      description: "Image One"
    },
    {
      src : img2, description: "Image Two"
    },
    {
      src : img3, description: "Image Three"
    },
    {
      src : img4, description: "Image Four"
    },
    {
      src : img5, description: "Image Five"
    }
  ];
  

  const nextSlide = () => {
      if (currentSlide >= TOTAL_SLIDES) { 
        setCurrentSlide(0);
      } else {
        setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
      }
    };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      setCurrentSlide(TOTAL_SLIDES);
    } else {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    slideRef.current.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentSlide}00%)`; 
    
  }, [currentSlide]);
return (
    <Container>
      <SliderContainer ref={slideRef}>
      
      {images.map(image => (
        <div>
          <h1 className="description">{image.description}</h1>
          <IMG src={image.src} key={image} />
          
        </div>
      ))}
      </SliderContainer>
      <ButtonP onClick={prevSlide}><h2>PREVIOUS</h2></ButtonP>
      
      <ButtonN onClick={nextSlide}><h2>NEXT</h2></ButtonN>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Slider;
```

**This is the slide.js code:**

```
export const IMG = styled.img `
  width: 399px;
  height: 200px;
  position:center;
  display: inline-block;
`;

export const Container = styled.div `
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-left:20%;
    displya: flex;
`;
export const ButtonP = styled.button `
  all: unset;
  width: "100px";
  height: "30px";
  border: 2px solid skyblue ;
  position:left;
  padding-right: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #727cff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #727cff;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;

export const ButtonN = styled.button `
  all: unset;
  width: "100px";
  height: "30px";
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  position:right;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: #727cff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #727cff;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;


export const SliderContainer = styled.div `
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
`;
```

I dont know whats wrong in the code or why it is being displayed like this

Comment: Well, without a snippet it's a bit tricky to find what's wrong, but I can see some problems: There is no such thing as `position:center`, at least I've never heard about; also there is a typo in `display`, you wrote `displya`. Maybe you img is larger than your container, try with `max-with: 100%` instead of `width:399px`.

Comment: max-width dosent work...it becomes too maximized and the buttons disappear as well.

Comment: Well, since you're using `flexbox` and your images are all in the same row, maybe what's happening is that the window where the image is being shown is larger than the image itself, in other words, the images are side by side and your container fits more than one. If that's the case you should calculate the required space and make the width of your container the same as the images, so that they will have the same width and there will be no left spaces to fit more than one image. If that's not the case and you want to create a snippet I can take a look, otherwise this is just a guessing game.